# How to increase root partition size by shrinking home partition using gparted live usb?

Tags: partition, gparted

I have Windows and Arch Linux installed in my system. I plan to increase the size of my root partition by shrinking the home partition using GParted live USB. But there is a swap partition between my root and home partition. I thought of shrinking the home partition and adding space to the swap and then shrink the swap then add it to the root since the unallocated space must be adjacent to the one being resized. I am not sure whether this going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the size of the swap partition, you just need to move it:

1. Shrink the home partition, the freed space is now between swap and home.
2. Move the swap partition, so that the freed space is between swap and root partition.
3. Increase root partition.

Comment: After doing this, will I need to make some changes in the fstab file or something?

Comment: No need to change anything afterwards. You only change the start and end positions of the partitions.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

When I did it, I deleted `swap` and re-created: `swap` does not rely on persistence, it is only using the cheapness / size of secondary storage.

I did have to change the `uuid` of `swap` in `/etc/fstab`

Reason to do it this way:

To avoid moving the big-ish swap partition (faster, not wear-out secondary storage device).